# Scapy PcapReader: Unknown LL Type [197]/[0xc5]. Using raw packets. Warning

Tags: python, parsing, pcap, scapy

I am using Python with the Scapy libraries to read and write `.cap` files, however one of my `.pcap` files is giving me this error/warning when reading it and no packets are being written to the output. Other `.pcap` files are working fine (ones which I have recorded myself).

Below is the code, I am using. Any help on the subject is appreciated.

```
from scapy.all import *
import os

count = 0

file_name = "/root/Desktop/test.pcap"

data = rdpcap(file_name)

os.system("clear")

filtered = (pkt for pkt in data 
    if UDP in pkt)

def counting(count):
    for pkt in data[UDP]:
        count += 1
    print count

counting(count)
wrpcap("/root/Desktop/testing.pcap", filtered)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning states that the specified file holds packets with link type `197` which is not supported by `scapy`, and thus the packets are interpreted as raw packets.

Since these are raw packets, `scapy` can't locate the `UDP` layer within them. Thus, the expression `(pkt for pkt in data if UDP in pkt)` evaluates to a generator with no items to yield.

Therefore, when executing `wrpcap("/root/Desktop/testing.pcap", filtered)` an empty file is written.

---

Searching for this link type [here](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) reveals that `tcpdump` names this link type as `LINKTYPE_ERF` and that it represents various link-layer types, with a pseudo-header, for `Endace DAG` cards and that it encapsulates `Endace ERF` records.

Some more light research reveals that you may convert the specified file from `ERF` format to ordinary `pcap` format that is supported by `scapy`. There are some online resources that can help you in the process such as [this](http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2012-11&post=Convert-Endace-ERF-capture-files-to-PCAP) and [this](http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2012-11&post=Convert-Endace-ERF-capture-files-to-PCAP). Since `Wireshark` [supports this format](http://wiki.wireshark.org/ERF), you can also open the file via `Wireshark` and save it in a different format.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will give this a go. I was using .pcap files which I had simply "saved as" .pcap from a .erf file, I was unaware about the encapsulation.